# (Dart, Flutter) How I can show image in list from database (image in base64 WebP)?

Tags: flutter, dart, webp

This is my string in database and object **Product** (field **mainPhoto**):

```
data:image/webp;base64,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
```

And this is my widget row of list:

```
Widget _buildRow(Product product, i) {
    int itemCount = 0;
    return Card(
        child: ListTile(
            leading: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: const Size.fromRadius(25),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: product.mainPhoto != null
              ? Text(product.mainPhoto!.substring(1, 6))
              : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

How I can show this image in listview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Image.memory(base64Decode("<base64-string-here>"));` to render image from bytes (base64 string was decoded to bytes). Check docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html.

Just remember to import `dart:convert` package and use only base64 part of your string (remove `data:image/webp;base64,`), so it should look like this:

```
Image.memory(base64Decode("UklGRowhAABXRUJQVlA..."))
```